# How can I reduce a collection by keeping only change points?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nedb

I have a Collection exampled below. This data is pulled from an endpoint every twenty minutes on a cron job.

```
{"id":AFFD6,"empty":8,"capacity":15,"ready":6,"t":1474370406,"_id":"kROabyTIQ5eNoIf1"}
    {"id":AFFD6,"empty":9,"capacity":15,"ready":5,"t":1474116005,"_id":"kX0DpoZ5fkMr2ezg"}
    {"id":AFFD6,"empty":9,"capacity":15,"ready":5,"t":1474684808,"_id":"ken1WRN47PTW159H"}
    {"id":AFFD6,"empty":9,"capacity":15,"ready":5,"t":1474117205,"_id":"kes1gDlG1sBjgV1R"}
    {"id":AFFD6,"empty":10,"capacity":15,"ready":4,"t":1474264806,"_id":"khILUjzGEPOn0c2P"}
    {"id":AFFD6,"empty":9,"capacity":15,"ready":5,"t":1474275606,"_id":"ko9r8u860es7E2hI"}
    {"id":AFFD6,"empty":9,"capacity":15,"ready":5,"t":1474591207,"_id":"kpLS6mCtkIiffTrN"}
```

I want to discard any document (row) that doesn't show a change in the `empty` (and consequently `ready`). My goal is to find the most recent time stamp where these values have changed with in this collection.

Better illustrated, I want to reduce it to where the values change as such:

```
{"id":AFFD6,"empty":8,"capacity":15,"ready":6,"t":1474370406,"_id":"kROabyTIQ5eNoIf1"}
{"id":AFFD6,"empty":9,"capacity":15,"ready":5,"t":1474117205,"_id":"kes1gDlG1sBjgV1R"}
{"id":AFFD6,"empty":10,"capacity":15,"ready":4,"t":1474264806,"_id":"khILUjzGEPOn0c2P"}
{"id":AFFD6,"empty":9,"capacity":15,"ready":5,"t":1474591207,"_id":"kpLS6mCtkIiffTrN"}
```

Can I do this at the in a MongoDB query? Or am I better off with a JavaScript filter function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB allows you to specify a unique constraint on an index. These constraints prevent applications from inserting documents that have duplicate values for the inserted fields.

Use the following code to make unique

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "id": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Also refer the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) for more clarification.